# Are Mystery Gifts bound to a single save?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

If I collect a mystery gift in my game, then delete that game and start a new one, will I be able to collect that mystery gift in my new game, or is it lost forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you delete your saved game and any wonder cards, you can continue to get the mystery gift until the promo stops. I already tried this myself and it worked.